# Is $\text{SL}(2, \mathbf Z)\simeq\text{Aut}(\mathbf P^1(\mathbf Z))$?

Tags: integers, projective-space, modular-group

In the section "Over discrete rings" in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line_over_a_ring) Wikipedia page, it is remarked that

> Similarly, a homography of P(Q) corresponds to an element of the modular group, the automorphisms of P(Z).

I asked someone who knows more than me and they said they could not find a reliable source for this remark-- that it might not be true. In addition, I found a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545843/projective-lines-over-mathbbq-and-mathbbz) asking about this line; in the answers, it said that the entire page was written strangely and that the line was later deleted (but I guess it was re-added to the page?).

Specifically, I'm asking about the last part. Is $\text{SL}(2,\mathbf Z)$ isomorphic to the automorphism group of the projective line over the integers?

Comment: I didn't know schemes were needed to answer this question. Doesn't the set of homographies from a projective space to itself form a group under composition?

Comment: I don't think I understand. The fixed structure would here be $\mathbf P^1(\mathbf Z)$, and the automorphisms would be fractional linear transformations that map $(z:1)$ to $(az+b:cz+d)$, would it not? Is there not enough structure to call this group of transformations an automorphism group?

Comment: Perhaps the cross ratio of four points may have a ring analog that would be preserved by such maps?

Answer (score 0):

The projective line $\mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{Z}$ over the integers is defined as the set of all pairs of integers modulo the equivalence relation induced by by nonzero integer scalar multiples. Its automorphism group is the *modular group*, meaning $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}),$ with trivial center, not $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}),$ which has a center of size 2.

To see this, consider the images $(a;c)$ and $(b;d)$ of $(1;0)$ and $(0;1),$ respectively, under an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{Z}.$
$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$
must have determinant 1 if I have written both $(a;c)$ and $(b;d)$ in lowest terms: otherwise, surjectivity would fail; one can show this by showing that $(1;0)$ and $(0;1)$ would not end up in the range by the Euclidean algorithm. Furthermore, the whole automorphism is carried out by this matrix.

One can use the matrices
$$S=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\mathrm{\quad\quad and\quad\quad}T=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ and their inverses to generate all of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}),$ or alternatively to carry out the Euclidean algorithm to find the greatest common factor of two numbers. Finally, $-I$ has a trivial action on the projective line, so we quotient out by the center of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ to get a faithful action.

Comment: Hi, I am not quite sure, but isn't the map from $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Z})$ to $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{Q})$ in fact a bijection?

Comment: Yes! Any point of the latter can be written as a point in the former by clearing denominators.

Comment: What does "automorphism group" mean here? As a scheme or something else? How does this argument show that every automorphism has this form?